# HttpWebRequest - Как получить ответ сервера при ошибке 429?

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

При посылке запроса с айпи тор в браузере - видно что ответ на запрос с кодом 429, но при этом в ответе код страницы с капчей, которую надо решить.

При посылке запроса через HttpWebRequest:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
//попытка прочитать ответ, из-за кода 429 сюда не заходит
}
```

из-за ошибки не могу прочитать страницу с капчей
Как можно получить тело ответа сервера при ошибке 429 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть миллион ответов на всех языках StackOverflow, поясняющих что `HttpWebRequest` устарел.

Но я еще раз поясню: `HttpWebRequest` не рекомендуется для новой разработки, об этом написано в его [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-5.0#remarks).

> Мы не рекомендуем использовать `HttpWebRequest` для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) класс.

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async Task<string> GetPageAsync(string url)
{
    using var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // диагностика
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{url} - {(int)response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
    }
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Использовать

```cs
string html = await GetPageAsync("https://ru.stackoverflow.com");
```

Если не знаете, что такое `async/await` - [вам сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: да, так работает. спасибо!